# Random.choice Only Choosing from One Line of File

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python novice here, very good at copy and pasting. I'm trying to sample one random word from my text file. It's working, but it's only sampling from a single line. How can I make it sample the entire file?

```
    lines = open("myfilehere").readlines()
    line = lines[0]

    words = line.split()
    print(random.choice(words))
    Labely = random.choice(words)
    Label1 = Label(root, text=Labely)
    Label1.pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You split and perform random.choice() on the variable words, which contains only your first line of text (lines[0]). If you want all the text you don't need to use the variable line, run `words = lines.split()` instead of `words = line.split()`

Comment: Thank you! I stopped using line and converted ```lines``` to str.

Answer (score 0):

First put all words into a list, then choose words from that list:

```
words=[]                            #Define an empty list
with  open("myfilehere") as fi:     #Open the file
   for line in fi:                  #Iterate over each line in file
     for word in line.split():      #Iterate over each word in line
         words.append(word)         #Add the word to the list

print(words)

Labely = random.choice(words)
```